# Finding $\lim_{n \to \infty}\sum_{k=1}^n\sqrt{\frac{k(k+1)}{n^2+k}}$

Tags: limits, proof-verification

## Problem

Evaluate
$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\left[\sqrt{\frac{1\cdot2}{n^2+1}}+\sqrt{\frac{2\cdot3}{n^2+2}}+\cdots+\sqrt{\frac{n(n+1)}{n^2+n}}\right],n=1,2,\cdots.$$

## Solution

Notice that, for $k=1,2,\cdots,n$,
$$ \sqrt{\frac{k\cdot(k+1)}{n^2+k}} \geq \frac{k}{\sqrt{n^2+n}}\geq \frac{k}{\sqrt{n^2+n^2}}=\frac{k}{n\sqrt{2}}$$
Therefore
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n}\sqrt{\frac{k\cdot(k+1)}{n^2+k}}\geq \sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{k}{n\sqrt{2}}=\frac{n+1}{2\sqrt{2}}\to+\infty(n \to \infty).$$
As a result
$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\sqrt{\frac{k\cdot(k+1)}{n^2+k}}=+\infty.$$

**Please check my solution.**

Comment: Looks good to me.

Comment: No problem for me neither.

Comment: The limit of $1/n$ times that sum is more interesting, I think...